# How to implement location search in android app?

Tags: android, search, kotlin, geolocation, openstreetmap

I am using OpenStreetMap in this kotlin based android app I am making. I want the user to be able to search on locations, then get a list of all places that match the keyword. I dont know where to begin and what to use, any ideas here?

Comment: See [OSM search engines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) (aka geocoders), especially Nominatim and Photon.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all i think you should check if there's a Web API for the OpenStreetMap so the Android Application can communicate with the server and database of this OpenStreetMap and there will be a documentary over there helping you continue the work!

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps has an API that allows you to search for a place by name.  If you get several results that match, they are returned in an array of points.  OpenStreetMaps may have a similar API, but if not, you could still use the Google Map API to do the search, then once you get results, you could plot them on the OpenStreetMap.